# is it relatively safe to union two tables with UUID PK?

Tags: postgresql, union, uuid

I want to union two tables whose primary keys are UUID(V4) and I want to preserve them in the result. I work with PostgreSQL

1. Is it safe to do this?
2. What are the pitfalls may be encountered?

Comment: Hmm, why wouldn't it be safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your concern is that the UUIDs could no longer be unique after the `UNION`.

That is of course theoretically possible, but the danger is no bigger that if you use version-4 UUIDs as primary keys.

In practice, you don't have to worry about that. Wikipedia [describes it well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Collisions):

> with [...] random version-4 UUIDs, collisions can occur even without implementation problems, albeit with a probability so small that it can normally be ignored. This probability can be computed precisely based on analysis of the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).
>
> For example, the number of random version-4 UUIDs which need to be generated in order to have a 50% probability of at least one collision is 2.71 quintillion, computed as follows:
>
> [image: qqq]
>
> This number is equivalent to generating 1 billion UUIDs per second for about 85 years. A file containing this many UUIDs, at 16 bytes per UUID, would be about 45 exabytes.

If you paranoid enough to be afraid of that, you shouldn't use version-4 UUIDs at all, but use a different, collision-free UUID algorithm like version 1 or 2.